# Non-linearly Independent Result in Calculating Generalized Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector

I am trying to find a basis for the generalized eigenvectors of the operator whose matrix is $T=\begin{bmatrix}2&1&0&4\\0&2&-1&0\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&3\end{bmatrix}$, following the method on Wikipedia for generalized eigenvectors. From what I've gathered so far, the eigenvalues are 2 multiplicity 2, 1 multiplicity 1, and 3 multiplicity 1. The eigenvectors for these eigenvalues are spanned by the respective vectors: $v_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},v_2\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix},v_3=\begin{pmatrix}7\\-1\\1\\2\end{pmatrix}$. Since 2 has multiplicity 2, it should have generalized eigenvectors spanned by some $v_4$, found by solving $Tv_4=\begin{bmatrix}2&1&0&4\\0&2&-1&0\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}=v_1$ where $v_4=\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}$. When I do this, I seem to get $v_4=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2}\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$, since $3d=0$ so $d=0$, $c+d=c=0$, $2b-c=2b=0$ so $b=0$ which isn't linearly independent from $v_1$. Where is my mistake in using this method?

Comment: $2b-c=0$ (from $Tv_4=v_1$) becomes $2b-0=0$ by substituting for $c=0$. Note as per my answer below, I found my mistake and these equations aren't correct for finding the generalized eigenvector.

Answer (score 1):

I see what I did, I was solving $Tv_4=v_1$ instead of $(T-2I)v_4=v_1$. Solving $(T-2I)v_4=v_1$ yields $\begin{pmatrix}a\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$, or $\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ for $a=0$.

Answer (score 0):

when everything involved is integers, I like reversing and finding the generalized eigenvector(s) first; here the minimal polynomial is  equal to the characteristic. An actual eigenvector comes from $(T-2I)v = 0.$ To make things consistent for the Jordan form, We choose column vector $w$ with $(T-2I)w \neq 0$  but $(T-2I)^2w = 0.$ We might as well take $w = (0,1,0,0)^t.$  The corresponding eigenvector is $ u =(T-2I)w \neq 0,$   we get  $u = (1,0,0,0)^t.$

$$
R =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1&0&-1&7\\
0&1&1&-1\\
0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&2\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

gives $R^{-1}TR = J $   in Jordan form.

Comment: Calculating the $(T-2I)^2$ matrix would be a bit tedious though, wouldn't it? Also, while finding the generalized eigenvectors forced might work, shouldn't the method where I found the regular eigenvectors first work also?

Comment: in the forward direction, you need some  column $w$ with $(T-2I)w = v_1 =(1,0,0,0)^t$ which was your $2$ eigenvector. That system will turn out to be consistent